# Xcode 14 - Warning Running UI Tests on M1 (Specified architecture not Compatible)

Tags: xcode

I am facing the below warning in Xcode console. Any ideas?

```
Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path 
'/Users/abhishek.bedi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
<MyProject>-hbkaixyoplhkzbdfcgkfxrqdklqt/Build/Products/
QA-iphonesimulator/MyUITests-Runner.app'- using an 
empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from
remote devices: the specified architecture 
'arm64-*-*' is not compatible with 'x86_64-apple-ios11.0.0-simulator'
```